# How to use abstract class variables in sub class static method

Tags: apex

**Subclass**

```
public with sharing class Processor extends Demo {
  public static void doOperation(List<Id> processIds) {
    // use abstract class variable here
  }
}
```

**Abstract Class**

```
abstract public with sharing class Demo {
  public static List< ProcessList > plList = new List< ProcessList >(); // How to use this list in above class static method.
}
```

I get this error - If I try using this list in my class I get this error -

> Variable does not exist: plList

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? What error do you get? Please [edit] to add detail.

Comment: If I try using this list in my class I get this error - Variable does not exist: plList

I also initialize the list in my abstract class like this
public List< ProcessList > plList {get; set;}

    public Demo(){
        this.plList = new List< ProcessList >();
    }

But still I get same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables must be referenced via a qualified name except when they are in the current class.

As such, to access this list you need to qualify it to the class it is in, i.e. using `Demo.plList` here, even in subclasses.

```
public with sharing class Processor extends Demo {
  public static void doOperation(List<Id> processIds) {
    Demo.plList = ...; // Example of setting it

    for (ProcessList pl : Demo.plList) { // Example of accessing it
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this helps. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. If the question is satisfactorily answered, please mark the answer as "best" to close it off. Thanks.